# websocket and VSCode port forwarding

Tags: javascript, python, visual-studio-code, websocket

I am working on a webapp that uses websockets and talk with a server written in python.
I have this recurrent problem where port forwarding in VsCode seems to keep dead sockets alive.  Here's the setup.

- In the webapp, I open a websocket to the server. If the server is not present, the websocket calls the error callback where I destroy it (call close and set to null). When this happens, I get an error like `Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at ws://localhost:8765/`. I then retry 500msec later.
- In the Python server, I uses the [Websockets](https://github.com/aaugustin/websockets) module. I designed a synchronous wrapper around the async library because my python app is designed to be synchronous. The wrapper is [here](https://github.com/scrutinydebugger/scrutiny-python/blob/master/scrutiny/server/tools/synchronous_websocket_server.py).
- When I develop, my server runs in a Ubuntu VM and the webapp is stored in the same VM.  I uses VsCode LiveServer plugin to serve the webapp (through the ssh plugin).

So. In order for this setup to work, LiveServer automatically forwards port 5500 which make my webapp available on my windows machine through localhsot:5500. This always have worked flawlessly.  Now, for my webapp (that runs in my Windows Firefox browser) to talk with the python server on Ubuntu, I also manually forward port 8765 (the one I use).

It all works (generally). But if I launch the webapp first, with port forwarding enabled bu the server is down, I have problems.  As mentionned, the webapp fails to connect and retry again and again.  All of these socket, altough closed on the browser side seems to stay active in vscode port forwarding feature. Once that happen, even if I start the server, the webapp stays in that state where it fails to connect continuously until I stop/start the port forwarding; then vscode flushes all the buffered socket to the server and it starts receiving a bunch of incoming connection that all closes right away. See the logs

```
2023-02-22 21:38:10.281 [INFO] <WebsocketClientHandler> Client disconnected (ID=54a78428e6444e2f8f0db88773f5e544). 0 clients remainings
2023-02-22 21:38:10.282 [INFO] <WebsocketClientHandler> New client connected (ID=d2a266bf93f84fa2b6b70523e15543e0). 1 clients total
2023-02-22 21:38:10.294 [INFO] <WebsocketClientHandler> Client disconnected (ID=d2a266bf93f84fa2b6b70523e15543e0). 0 clients remainings
2023-02-22 21:38:10.295 [INFO] <WebsocketClientHandler> New client connected (ID=7687380cb1de4d13b2460f904dfaae2f). 1 clients total
2023-02-22 21:38:10.307 [INFO] <WebsocketClientHandler> Client disconnected (ID=7687380cb1de4d13b2460f904dfaae2f). 0 clients remainings
2023-02-22 21:38:10.307 [INFO] <WebsocketClientHandler> New client connected (ID=b8cb24da688b44d0a3a3f4c518b00732). 1 clients total
2023-02-22 21:38:10.318 [INFO] <WebsocketClientHandler> Client disconnected (ID=b8cb24da688b44d0a3a3f4c518b00732). 0 clients remainings
2023-02-22 21:38:10.319 [INFO] <WebsocketClientHandler> New client connected (ID=8d929c0b816c4888a846a1af24e545cd). 1 clients total
2023-02-22 21:38:10.330 [INFO] <WebsocketClientHandler> Client disconnected (ID=8d929c0b816c4888a846a1af24e545cd). 0 clients remainings
2023-02-22 21:38:10.330 [INFO] <WebsocketClientHandler> New client connected (ID=f0d99dbeb5cd44619f3953fc54e42a1f). 1 clients total
2023-02-22 21:38:10.343 [INFO] <WebsocketClientHandler> Client disconnected (ID=f0d99dbeb5cd44619f3953fc54e42a1f). 0 clients remainings
2023-02-22 21:38:10.346 [INFO] <WebsocketClientHandler> New client connected (ID=99265e71358c4a58bafb1b18c320970e). 1 clients total
2023-02-22 21:38:10.357 [INFO] <WebsocketClientHandler> Client disconnected (ID=99265e71358c4a58bafb1b18c320970e). 0 clients remainings
2023-02-22 21:38:10.358 [INFO] <WebsocketClientHandler> New client connected (ID=671bffa2d5164b0599006f5fc8ef7766). 1 clients total
2023-02-22 21:38:10.369 [INFO] <WebsocketClientHandler> Client disconnected (ID=671bffa2d5164b0599006f5fc8ef7766). 0 clients remainings
```

In order to avoid any problem, I need to start things in this sequence.  Port forwarding, server, webapp. If there are some "dead socket" in the proxy, I either have to purge them by stop/start the port forwarding or restarting vscode. Sometime stop/start is not enough and vscode never seems to recover; in that case I restart it and everything comes back to normal.

So. Am I doing anything wrong or is VsCode port forwarding weak? When I work in local, I never get problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found out there is an open bug at microsoft.
All of my websockets stays in WAIT_CLOSE state.

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/3561